# Move variable from one function to another (in Django user registration), python

Tags: python, django, variables, global

I am quite new to this and I have been trying this for several hours, and it is not working. I will be very grateful if you could please help me. Thank you so much.

Here is my code:

```
def login_view(request):

    username1 = request.POST['username']
    password1 = request.POST['password']
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username1, password=password1)
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        # Correct password, and the user is marked "active"
        auth.login(request, user)
        # Redirect to a success page.
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/account/loggedin/")
    else:
        # Show an error page
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/account/invalid/")



def profile_page(request):
    html = loader.get_template('profile_test.html')
    login_view(request)
    c = Context({'user' : username1})
    return HttpResponse(html.render(c))
```

Everything works perfectly, when I put username1 in profile_page in quotes. However, when I use username1 as a global variable, it does not work. How can I use username1 as a global variable? Thank you so much, I have been trying all sorts of things for hours now, but nothing works. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

because the HttpResponse is not returned the login_view call does nothing.

if your user is logged in then any request should automatically contain that user. so, for example:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    user = request.user
    context['user'] = user.username
```

otherwise you could pass the user in the url and then get the username in the view (or just use the user object in the template and insert {{ user.username }} into your template.